# I can't set up the validator correctly to register and log in to the flutter project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I've moved the TextFormFiled widget to a separate class and styles for it. in theory, I correctly wrote the logic for the validator, but for some reason it does not work, after clicking on the Get Started button, if the line is empty, then an error about this should appear, and if the mail is not specified correctly, then the password is the same, similarly, but why does nothing happen after clicking on the button

**Here are the lines of code:**

```
class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  final FirebaseAuthServices _auth = FirebaseAuthServices();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final _confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();

  String? validateEmail(String? email) {
    RegExp emailRegex = RegExp(r'^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$');
    final isEmailValid = emailRegex.hasMatch(email ?? '');
    if (!isEmailValid) {
      return "Please enter a valid email";
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    _confirmPasswordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            "assets/images/back_signup.png",
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Please enter your details",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 38,
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 22),
                  CustomTextField(
                    textColor: Colors.grey,
                    hintText: "Email",
                    controller: _emailController,
                    obscureText: false,
                    width: 326,
                    validator: validateEmail,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 18),
                  CustomTextField(
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    controller: _passwordController,
                    hintText: "Password",
                    obscureText: true,
                    width: 326,
                    validator: (password) => password!.length < 6
                        ? "Password must be at least 6 characters long"
                        : null,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 18),
                  CustomTextField(
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    controller: _confirmPasswordController,
                    hintText: "Confirm Password",
                    obscureText: true,
                    width: 326,
                    validator: (password) => password!.length < 6
                        ? "Password must be at least 6 characters long"
                        : null,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 18),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 326,
                    height: 45,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          _signUp();
                        }
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "Get Started",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _signUp() async {
    String email = _emailController.text;
    String password = _passwordController.text;
    String confirmPassword = _confirmPasswordController.text;

    if (password != confirmPassword) {
      _showErrorDialog("Passwords do not match");
      return;
    }

    User? user = await _auth.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    if (user != null) {
      print("User created: ${user.email}");
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      _showErrorDialog("Failed to create user");
    }
  }

  void _showErrorDialog(String message) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Error"),
          content: Text(message),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text("OK"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code for the CustomTextField widget

```
@override


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
      child: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: widget.width ?? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
          height: widget.height,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                validator: widget.validator,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                controller: widget.controller,
                obscureText: widget.obscureText && !_showPassword,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: widget.hintText,
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                ),
                style: _style,
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
              if (widget.obscureText)
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _showPassword = !_showPassword;
                    });
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    _showPassword ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I reproduced your code [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=f3a772c948d5dc5b7fc209d87fdbd230) and I don't see any issues. The only difference between our code is the `CustomTextField` widget, so the issue must have something to do with that. Please provide your code for `CustomTextField`.

Comment: @Texv I've added the code below

Comment: In your `CustomTextField`, you're fetching the validator but not using it anywhere. In the TextFormField widget you need to add `validator: widget.validator`. Same applies to your textColor and width, you're not applying it anywhere in your CustomTextField

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the validator to your `CustomTextField`, so far so good

```
CustomTextField(validator: validateEmail),
```

But you forgot to use it in your `CustomTextField`

```
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final FormFieldValidator<String>? validator;
  const CustomTextField({required this.validator,}) : super(key: key);
... TextFormField(
validator: widget.validator, //Add this
```

You're also not using the `width` and `textColor` parameters. You can make it have a default value and not require it to be called unless you want something different than the default just like you did with the height parameter.

```
 class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
   final Color textColor;
   final double? width; //make nullable

   const CustomTextField({
     this.textColor = Colors.white, //remove required, set default color
     this.width, //remove required, set default null
  }) : super(key: key);

    ...SizedBox(
         width: widget.width ?? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8, //change to specified value, otherwise default
    ... initState(
          _style = TextStyle(
            color: widget.controller.text.isNotEmpty ? widget.textColor : Colors.grey, //apply the color
          );)
```

#### After Edit:

Your error message changes the size of the field because in your `CustomTextField` widget your parent `SizedBox` widget has a maximum height of 42. You need to remove the height parameter to make it flexible.

```
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final FormFieldValidator<String>? validator;
  const CustomTextField({required this.validator,}) : super(key: key);
... SizedBox(
      width: widget.width ?? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
      //height: widget.height, //REMOVE THIS/comment out
```

Also the icon won't move because it is separately positioned within a Stack. Instead of using Stack widget, use the `suffixIcon` parameter in your TextFormField's InputDecoration.

```
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     suffixIcon: widget.obscureText 
       ? IconButton(
           onPressed: () {setState(() {_showPassword = !_showPassword;});},
           icon: Icon(_showPassword ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off, color: Colors.grey,),) 
       : SizedBox.shrink(),
```

See full code and demo here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=20a525bb9589bbe9b4d1772010e77203

Comment: @ Texv **For some reason, the design of the line fell down with an error, so I added that the frame was red, but the size of the line changes, and I don't know how to make it so that it is the same as when it was launched**

Comment: @Roman you edited your question to make it look like another question, that's unnecessary. The reason why the error eats up the space is because you specified a specific height. SizedBox(height: widget.height) which is 42. Since the height cannot expand to show the error, it shrinks. Simply remove the height parameter from the SizedBox. So only provide the width and nothing else

Comment: I edited my answer to fix the UI issue with the height and icon